# Mapping akka stream source[A,B] to source[A,NotUsed]

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

I've just started using akka streams so this may be a trivial question, however I haven't found an answer to it.

I have an input stream with type [String, Something] and I need to get rid of the auxiliary data and get a Source[String,NotUsed].

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Some example code:

```
def f():Source[String, NotUsed] = {
    val s=Source[String, Subscriber[String]] = Source.asSubscriber[String]
    ... // connect the source to a graph

    val o=??? //map s to Source[String,NotUsed]
    o
}
```

Comment: do you have any code to see clearer what you want to mean?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 added.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
val o: Source[String, NotUsed] = s.mapMaterializedValue(_ => NotUsed)
```

or

```
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
val o: Source[String, NotUsed] = s.preMaterialize()._2
```